# Where does it come from vs What does it come from

Tags: prepositions

Do both work?

I could only assume that both are grammatically correct...

As an example:

Let's say that there is a word that derives from a name, such as "sandwich" which was coined from a name of somebody.

But let's say that we want to ask the name of the person that it came from.

We would ask:
"Where does it come from?"

but I feel like that the phrase:
"What does it come from?"

is applicable and even more plausible when asking for the origins of words, as some might not have come from names or places.

Comment: *Where* is the interrogative for place; *what* is the interrogative for nature. Where makes you think you can swap the two in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, but let's say the scenario is that a word is coined from a name. (For this example let's say "Sandwich")

Comment: Then we could ask "Where does it come from?" and maybe also "What does it come from?" because it's not from a place, but a name.

Comment: What I'm saying is both questions are grammatical and sensible, but are asking very different things. Do you want to know about place (which applies in the abstract as much as it does in the concrete) or about nature? Please [edit] your question  to include several complete examples of the kinds of questions you want to ask?

Comment: If you see a kid with four hands and two heads walking in the streets, you can say "what does it come from"  in which case you are questioning what his parents are rather than ask "where does it come from" which enquires about his home, whether it is on this planet or not is an entirely different question.

Comment: @DanBron I have edited the question, please take a look at it..

Comment: @vickyace How would my question be applied to the example I have put on the edited question?

Comment: Who does it come from: for a person.

Comment: @Lambie What about for an elephant? What if a name derives from an elephant? How would you ask its origin?

Comment: Who, what, where does IT, HE, SHE, come from, are all relevant. :)

Comment: @JasonLee In all these cases, I'd say "where does it come from" to ask about origins. The phrasal verb "come from" sets up a locative context, so it's usually collocated with "where".

Comment: @Lambie How would I prove this to someone that thinks otherwise? Is there a grammatical term of concept that I can try to explain or recommend to make them understand? Such as a teacher that boldly claimed that it was strictly incorrect from a grammatical stand point.

Comment: @DanBron But would you say that both are GRAMMATICALLY correct?

Comment: [1/2] @JasonLee Grammatical correctness is a function of the *form* of an utterance, not its *content*. In particular it depends only on the parts of speech and order of the words in the sentence (and obviously also on morphology, but in a analytic language like English, syntax is more prominent). In other words if one is grammatically correct, the other must be too, because they only differ by one word, in the same location in the sentence, having the same part of speech. But what does that tell you? *Colorless green ideas sleep furiously* is also 100% grammatically correct.

Comment: [2/2] @JasonLee In other words, you're not concerned with grammar, but pragmatics (or semantics, I can't tell the difference between the two), and beyond that simple *sensibility*. And you already have my opinion on those points: both forms of the question *make sense*, but are *asking different things*, and in all the examples you personally have given, I would choose and prefer *Where?* over *What?*.

Comment: "Where does the word 'sandwich' come from?" is the standard idiom, using a positional / travel metaphor. "What is the derivation / etymology of the word 'sandwich'?" is a non-metaphorical alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if you know that it is named after a person you should use 'who is it named after?'. If you don't know 'where' is better than 'what', as 'where' is a place, and the use of 'coming from' fits with a 'place' (set of circumstances) from where the idea has come. If you *want* to use 'what', try 'what caused it to be called a sandwich?'.

Answer (score 0):

SANDWICH: as an example of words named for people.

Where does it come from? Originally from England.

Who was it named after? It was named after the Earl of Sandwich.

Where does the name Brazil come from? It comes from the name of a type of wood.
It was named after Brazil wood.

Where does the name America come from? It comes from Amerigo Vespucci.

It was named after him.